# Android / mobile browser developer tool for debugging

Tags: android, browser, cordova, remote-debugging

Is there any plugin or anything that allow easier web debugging on mobile browser? I have done some searching and I find about weinre. But it seems complicated to setup. I also tried with debug.phonegap.com. But it end up not working that it says "Target not connected".

So, is there any other way like plugin or weinre alternative for debugging like firebug?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best bet is weinre.

It's really not that complicated to setup. Just get [nodejs installed](http://nodejs.org/download/).

When node is installed type `npm install -g weinre` to install weinre.

Then type `weinre --boundHost 0.0.0.0`, it'll start weinre on your computer at port 8080.

Paste in the following in your HTML, replace `0.0.0.0` with your computers IP address, and you're ready to start debugging:

```
<script src="http://0.0.0.0:8080/target/target-script-min.js#anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I have go through the process. But when I try to see if it's working by putting "http://192.168.1.25:8080/target/target-script-min.js#anonymous" on browser address bar, browser load nothing. Seems like it is not working.

Comment: Yeah it doesn't do anything in the address bar, you need to include it in the page either from the start or from a bookmarklet. It needs to be run in the context of the page you want to debug

Comment: somewhere i saw an option for boundhost all for weinre... if you run into problems with weinre just bound all the hosts with the all option.. google it if you wanna learn about it more